# Why adding s to the sentence ".. to groups"

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

I am confusing with the following sentence from a writing book,

> People were randomly assigned to groups.

Although I agree and I think it is correct (instead of "to group"), 
but I don't know the reason.

Since the subject is plural, the verb should be without 's'.
However, using verb+s, feel more natural for me.

Comment: *Groups* is not a verb; it's a plural noun, an indirect object. The verb is *were*.

Comment: If "group" was going to be used as a verb here, you would have been right. "People were randomly assigned to group together."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because group is a noun and as your subject is plural so the noun will be plural too...

Answer (score 0):

Context matters too...

Consider

**all the people assigned to a single group** `vs` **people assigned to different groups.**

So in the sentence in your question, may be the `author` wants to convey that they are assigned to `different groups`

Perhaps, it does not make any sense to me assigning people in just `one group`.